# Bootstrap and JQuery layout anomaly on IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a simple image gallery for a website using Bootstrap and JQuery. Each image goes in a container (.square) which is 3 columns wide.

I've written some JQuery to make the container height always equal the container width, thereby creating a square for each image.

I've then styled the images to responsively fit the square. This allows me to handle a mixture of portrait and landscape images, in a 'nice' way.

This works great in just about every browser and device I've tried... except IE 11, where the grid system is thrown off. Works fine in Edge though.

Any thoughts on what's throwing it off (and how to fix it) would be appreciated. Equally, a suggestion for alternative ways to handle this would be helpful. It's important that I can mix and match portrait and landscape images, but keep everything centred horizontally and vertically.

Here is a screenshot of the problem.

[IE 11 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPnGR.png)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BelfastBert/v8wxanbj/2/) of the gallery page can be found here

Here is my page markup:

CSS:

```
    .square {}
    .gall_item{ max-height: 100%; 
                max-width: 100%; 
                width: auto; 
                height: auto; 
                position: absolute; 
                top: 0; 
                bottom: 0; 
                left: 0; 
                right: 0; 
                margin: auto; 
                padding: 2em 2em 2em 2em; }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="main container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/600x800">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/600x800">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(makeSq);
    $(document).ready(makeSq);
    $(window).resize(makeSq);

    function makeSq(){
        $(".square").each(function(){
            $(this).height($(this).width());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a row for your second set of 12 columns.
See HTML below, where I added the HTML elements in and added comments with what was missing.

```
<div class="main container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/600x800">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
            </div>   <!-- this was missing -->
        </div>   <!-- this was missing -->
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" >  <!-- this was missing -->
            <div class="row">   <!-- this was missing -->              
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/600x800">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 square">
                    <img class="gall_item" src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```